# How to customize the Ribbon from code in Excel 365?

Tags: excel, vba

I am familiar with the VBA routines needed for customising the Excel ribbon of Excel 2013 and below.

When trying to open the file on Excel 365 I get an error message:

[image]

Here is the code I use (that works on Excel 2010):

```
Sub CreateMenu()
    ' Delete the CommandBar if it exists already
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("My Tool").Delete

    Set cControl = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add
    With cControl
        .Caption = "My Tool"
        .Style = msoButtonCaption
    End With


End Sub
```

How should I modify the code to run on both Excel 2010 and Excel 365 versions?

Comment: Personally, I modify the ribbon via the UI and distribute it (`Excel.OfficeUI`) along with `xlam` add-ons. I did run into issues of hardcoded usersnames though and used `batchsubstitute` to swap my name for current `%USERNAME%`. I'm sure you'll figure it out, I'm not experienced in this to offer an answer, just an alternative method.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers: Thanks - but my Excel file is imported from csv/bas files - there is no real XSLM file in my environment. Also I can't modify the target computer environment (installing excel add-ins) - therefore i have to manipulate the ribbon from code during Excel open event

Comment: Manipulating the ribbon on excel open event is modifying the target computer isn't it? In fact in my testing it required "enable content" to be clicked where as distributing `Excel.OfficeUI` works without user intervention. Ribbons and Add-Ins are completely separate, I just use both in conjunction, but they don't really get "installed" per se, just placed in the proper startup directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is actually two questions IMO.

- How to make to code work for each version (differentiate between Office Versions)
- How to make the code work for Office 365

I did some research on Office 365 Ribbon Customization and found a few things I hope can help.

It has become much harder to differentiate between Office versions since Office365/2019. [You used to be able to just use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56385014/export-a-single-worksheet-to-a-new-workbook-using-vba-and-a-button/56387687?noredirect=1#comment99389380_56387687) `Select Case Int(Application.Version)` coupled with `Case 11/14` etc. But now everything 2016 and above just returns `Case 16`.

I found [a function to differentiate between Office Versions](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2019/02/11/check-the-application-version-in-modern-office/) and also some information that `CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add` has been ["superseded by the new ribbon component of the Microsoft Office Fluent user interface."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcontrols.add)

I don't have Office 365 to test how to modify your code, but once you get that part working, this is how you can implement the solution:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    If CStr(AppVersion) = 365 Then
    MsgBox "Office 365" 'Setup new code here for Office365
    ' See --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcontrols.add
    ' Note: The use of CommandBars in some Microsoft Office applications has been superseded by the new ribbon component of the Microsoft Office Fluent user interface.
    ' For more information, see Overview of the Office Fluent ribbon.
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/overview-of-the-office-fluent-ribbon
    Else
    MsgBox "Non-Office 365" ' Insert known working code here for older versions of Office/Excel or call seperate sub for Non-Office 365
    End If

End Sub

Private Function AppVersion() As Long
    'Test the Office application version
    'Written by Ken Puls (www.excelguru.ca)
    'https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2019/02/11/check-the-application-version-in-modern-office/

    Dim registryObject As Object
    Dim rootDirectory As String
    Dim keyPath As String
    Dim arrEntryNames As Variant
    Dim arrValueTypes As Variant
    Dim x As Long

    Select Case Val(Application.Version)

        Case Is = 16
        'Check for existence of Licensing key
        keyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Office\" & CStr(Application.Version) & "\Common\Licensing\LicensingNext"
        rootDirectory = "."
        Set registryObject = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & rootDirectory & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
        registryObject.EnumValues &H80000001, keyPath, arrEntryNames, arrValueTypes

        On Error GoTo ErrorExit
        For x = 0 To UBound(arrEntryNames)
            If InStr(arrEntryNames(x), "365") > 0 Then
                AppVersion = 365
                Exit Function
            End If
            If InStr(arrEntryNames(x), "2019") > 0 Then
                AppVersion = 2019
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next x

        Case Is = 15
            AppVersion = 2013
        Case Is = 14
            AppVersion = 2010
        Case Is = 12
            AppVersion = 2007
        Case Else
            'Too old to bother with
            AppVersion = 0
    End Select

  Exit Function

ErrorExit:
    'Version 16, but no licensing key.  Must be Office 2016
    AppVersion = 2016

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the function to differentiate between Excel versions... but from the documentation you mentioned (and reviewed already), there doesn't seem to be a solution for VBA coding to manipulate the Excel 365 ribbon.. only customUI XML embedded within the xslm file, right?

Comment: I'm uncomfortable saying yes or no, this looks promising --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.activatetabq

Comment: This is how I distribute my Macros + Customized Ribbon --> https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Distributing+Macro+via+Add-In+-+Customized+Ribbon+-+Via+Batch

Comment: So how did things turn out? I see you accepted, sorry the answer wasn't better regarding the actual customization.

Comment: I used your detection code to identified which version am i running, and for some reason applying the same routine on both excel versions worked for me